# Run PHP script in the background (without interrupting the user)?

Tags: php

I would like to run a PHP script in the background for logging visitor information (after the user's page has loaded), so that it doesn't slow the user down.

From what I have found, there are a few methods to achieving this, one is to launch a `popen` command, another is to use `exec`, and the last *I know of* is using `fsockopen` ([source](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3875021.htm)):

```
$socket = fsockopen($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],80,$errorno,$errorstr,10); 
if($socket) { 
   $socketdata = “GET /background_script.php HTTP 1.1\r\nHost: “.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].”\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n”; 
   fwrite($socket,$socketdata); 
   fclose($socket); 
}
```

My server doesn't allow the use of `popen` or `exec`, so that leaves me with `fsockopen`.

Is this the best method available to me?

Thanks for any support (:

**EDIT:**

Another possible solution which I have found could be to send `Connection: close` to the browser to stop the loading on the client side, and then `include` the `background_script`.

Is this solution recommended?

E.G:

```
ob_start();
echo $OUTPUT_DATA;
header("Content-Length: ".ob_get_length());
header('Connection: close');

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

//Do background visitor logging stuff here..
```

Comment: No `fsockopen` is not usable here. It will block the execution as well.

Comment: How is this a "background script"? Won't the `close` call block until the remote end has returned data? Btw: a better way to do this may be to send Javascript to the client which performs the analytics (such as the Google Analytics script).

Comment: Just output the whole page, and call [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) when it is complete. As long as the output has been sent to the browser it should be rendered, and anything you do after will not interrupt the user. The only disadvantage to this approach is that the page will still appear to be loading - but the whole thing should be usable.

Comment: @TimWolla, Oh, it does seem to work on my server, if I use `sleep()` in `background_script.php`, and get it to write a file ten seconds later, it performs fine (during that ten seconds, there is no page loading/waiting on the client side).   @Borealid, if I'm 100% honest, I'm not completely sure on how the example I provided works  ..I just copied the source directly from the linked site to test if it would be useful to me.  I wouldn't be able to use Javascript due to the page being loaded on the client side being formatted as JSON ..but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I've heard you can use PHP's "shutdown function" feature to do this, but I haven't got any experience with it.

Comment: @DaveRandom, thank you for your suggestion; unfortunately I will not be able to use that method as the output is intended to be parsed by Java on Android, which would not stop parsing until the page has finished loading (meaning it would slow the user down). @ Abhi, unfortunately, I could not find any documentation on that method, any links?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a queuing solution to fulfill your requirements which would work like this:

1. User logs in
2. PHP User function adds work to a 'login' queue
3. An 'always-on' PHP script (worker) is assigned work from the queue
4. Work is completed in the background

This approach is a little more advanced, in that you have to introduce a queue manager and php daemon(s) to handle the work, but it works great when completed.

I would suggest reading [some docs](http://gearman.org/) on 'Gearman', which has [built-in](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) php user functions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I think that an "always-on" script would be overkill for my needs (and frowned-upon by my host)  ..but that solution would maybe be useful for future reference

Comment: Understood. Where are you storing the user information between when the user logs in and when you want to run the background script?

Comment: There isn't as such a "log-in" process, just a "visitor" requesting a `.json.php` file. (Once a user loads the _dynamic json file_, I will get PHP to load all the data the user requires, then pass variables containing the visitor data to the "background" script, which would then store the data on a database.)  ..the logging of visitor data is purely for statistical purposes (:

Comment: Ahhh. You should include that in your OP. I have worked on systems where we had to do something similar, log user activity throughout the application. We ended up writing a class that would log user activity information to a flat-file, where it could be picked up and parsed by an outside process, scheduled via crontab.